# The failure retry mechanism of HttpClient in JDK11

Tags: java, http, java-http-client

I am currently using HttpClient in JDK11 (not Apache's HttpClient). These two HttpClients are similar, but I noticed that Apache's HttpClient can retry the request failure by overriding the `HttpRequestRetryHandler` class. But I did not find a similar implementation in JDK's HttpClient. How should I implement a similar failure retry mechanism?

Anyone's suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you get back a `CompletableFuture`, you can always write code to retry if that once fails. No such class exists by default, but it is not complicated to write it yourself

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpClient` will retry idempotent requests by default. It also retries when failing to connect. It is also possible to alter this default behavior by setting a couple of system properties on the command line (to disable retry on connect failures or enable retry for non idem-potent requests) but that's mostly for testing.

You could also retry a request by using the asynchronous API and registering a dependent action that will retry the request in case of failures - or depending on the returned response code - for instance by using `CompletableFuture::handle`.

Comment: I can't see any mention of this in the Javadoc for HttpClient (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html). Where is this behavior documented?

Comment: Documentation has been improved in later releases. Not all properties documented in the Java 21 API documentation may apply to Java 11 but most of them do. I would encourage switching to Java 21 if that's an option though.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html